# afxGlobalUtils.GetDockingManager(pParentFrame); returns NULL

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc, print-preview, afx

Having odd bug in my mfc single doc program (VS2008). When calling AFXPrintPreview(this), an assertion gets tripped. Looks like on line 181 of afxpreviewviewex.cpp, when mfc tries to get a hold of the docking manager, it just gets NULL, which trips an assert when mfc attempts to add a pane on line 183. Specifically, I get the print statement: ASSERT_VALID fails with NULL pointer. The parent frame being passed into GetDockingManager() is definitely my main frame. I would assume this means that there's some initialization my frame must be missing?

Comment: We cannot comment on code we cannot see. Please show a [mcve]. In the meantime, to debug the issue, you can single-step into `GetDockingManager()` to learn which of your assumptions do not match up with the code. It is implemented in *afxglobalutils.cpp*.

Comment: In future questions, I'll be sure to geta a minimal reproducible example going, I feel silly for not having done that at all to date. Thanks!

I've found a solution around the issue. My solution is super specific to the tech I'm using, which is proprietary, so I'm not sure posting my answer is actually going to be helpful to anybody. Should I just delete this one?

Comment: As the author of a question you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72048654/edit) it at any time. Provided a [mcve] is available that helps readers to determine, whether this matches the issue they are trying to solve, it is not unreasonable to assume that an answer can be useful, regardless of how specific it is.